# Why UI not displaying properly

Tags: user-interface, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm new to angular and I don't know why it looks odd (table not looks like proper ) while running snipet, it doesn't give me look and feel like datatable. 
 I want to give it UI like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4), i try to chnage version of css also, but it did not help. 
Can any one help me to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

```js
//Angularjs and jquery.datatable with ui.bootstrap and ui.utils

var app=angular.module('formvalid', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('validationCtrl',function($scope){
  var table = $('#ajaxExample').DataTable({
     "ajax" : {
      "url": "http://datatable.getsandbox.com/datatable",
      "dataSrc": "users",
      "headers": "Content-Type : application/json"
     },
     "columns" : [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "age" },
      { "data": "position" },
      { "data": "office" },
     ],
  });
 
});
```

```css
  table tr th{
    background:#337ab7;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>datatable using jquery.datatable in angularjs</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch'
   href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch'
   href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css'>
 </head>
<body>

 <div class="container" ng-app="formvalid">
  <div class="panel" data-ng-controller="validationCtrl">
   <div class="panel-heading border">
    <h2>Data table using jquery datatable in Angularjs</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <table id="ajaxExample" class="display" width="100%" ui-jq="datatable" ui-options="ajaxOptions">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Office</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
 <script
  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>
 <script
  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.0.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js'></script>
 <script
  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-utils/0.1.1/angular-ui-utils.min.js'></script>
 <script
  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
 <script
  src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach bootstrap table styling from the `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css` file, you need to add classes to your table element.

```
class="table table-striped table-bordered"
```

Otherwise you get the standard bootstrap table styling.

If you use the HTML tab on the page you link to, it shows you how the table on that page is styled.